# Pyinstaller error, No module named Tkinter yet works in IDE

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, python-import, pyinstaller

I know this question has been asked before however the solution of adding, `--hiddenimport=Tkinter` unfortunately isn't working for me.

My script has no errors when running in IDE. The script includes a Tkinter window, a webservice call using suds, and putting the data in excel using openpyxl.

I've been trying this to run this in cmd:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --onedir --hiddenimport=Tkinter my_script.py
```

It creates an exe, however it doesn't run, when I run it inside cmd, it says

```
ImportError: No module named Tkinkter
```

Comment: Let me guess... Are you using IDLE as your IDE?

Comment: I'm using PyScripter

Comment: Ok. You should mention that in the body of your question. It looks like PyScripter is using Tkinter itself (IDLE also does this).

Comment: BTW: pyinstaller can create `--onefile` or `--onedir`, not both at the same time. `--onedir` create directory with all files which you can copy on another computer to run , and you see what files it found. `--onefile` get the same files and create self-executable .ZIP with this files.